# pycharm code completion / syntax highlighting for django in haml files

Tags: django-templates, haml, pycharm

I just tried to use HAML in my django project, which works fine^^

But while writing beautiful HAML code PyCharm refuse to offer any code completion or syntax highlighting for django template tags like in HTML files.

Do I need to configure PyCharm differently or is it just not possible to get the "Django Support" in HAML files with PyCharm?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've found an older issue related to this one.

"At the moment the HAML support is part of the RubyMine code and can't be

used in other products. We have an issue for making it independent:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-6432"

Not sure if they managed to extract the HAML support to PyCharm or not. Their tracker is overloaded so I couldn't check it.